# How to use name in VLOOKUP from a cell value

Tags: excel

I defined a range with a name `Christmas2016` with data in a worksheet named `Raw`.

The range contains 3 rows with the first columns being `Announcement`, `Last Chance`, and `Final Hours`.

In another sheet named `Summary`, I have a two cells with the following values -

1. `B2` contains `Announcement`
2. `B3` contains `Christmas2016`

I want to run the `VLOOKUP` function - `VLOOKUP(B2, Christmas2016, 3, FALSE)`. This, of course, executes fine. However, I want to replace the hard-coded name `Christmas2016` and use the value in the cell `B3`.

I tried -

1. `VLOOKUP(B2, B3, 3, FALSE)`
2. `VLOOKUP(B2, &B3, 3, FALSE)`

None of these work. Is there a way to use names in the formulas that are stored as cell values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)  function is made for.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT(B3), 3, FALSE)
```